# calculating the magnitude of a pixel in cuda with shared memory

Tags: cuda, sift, gpu-shared-memory

I am working on a school project that we run the sift algorithm in cuda. I have at a point to calculate the magnitude value of every pixel(X) of an image based on the values of its neighbors(A,B,C,D):

```
   A
B  X  C
   D
```

I managed to make it by using global memory because I could easily get the values I wanted from my input array.

But now I want to make it by first putting the input array into shared memory but I am having a really tough time on how to make the threads put the right pixels on the shared memory. I must take into consideration the padding on the borders of the image.

I know that I need more shared memory than the part of image I want to put in there so that the padding will be included but I dont know if my thread block should contain more or less threads than the shared memory space and how to specify what to read.
If someone can give me a general idea on how to think for this I could take it from there...

Thanks!

Comment: For image processing applications, shared memory usage is a bit complex. I would recommend that you use CUDA textures. Texture reads are cached, and handling of border cases is really easy. Textures are best suited for neighborhood operations.

Comment: Which compute capability has your graphic device?

Answer (score 1):

I provided a code going through a gray scale image and appling sobel filter: (Sobel is a filter similar to your neighbor(A,B,C,D) function)

```
#define QUANTUM_TYPE short
__global__ void sobel_gpu(QUANTUM_TYPE *img_out, QUANTUM_TYPE *img_in, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT){
    int x,y;
    x=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
    y=blockDim.y*blockIdx.y+threadIdx.y;
    QUANTUM_TYPE LUp,LCnt,LDw,RUp,RCnt,RDw;
    int pixel;

    if(x<WIDTH && y<HEIGHT){
        LUp = (x-1>=0 && y-1>=0)? img_in[(x-1)+(y-1)*WIDTH]:0;
        LCnt= (x-1>=0)? img_in[(x-1)+y*WIDTH]:0;
        LDw = (x-1>=0 && y+1<HEIGHT)? img_in[(x-1)+(y+1)*WIDTH]:0;
        RUp = (x+1<WIDTH && y-1>=0)? img_in[(x+1)+(y-1)*WIDTH]:0;
        RCnt= (x+1<WIDTH)? img_in[(x+1)+y*WIDTH]:0;
        RDw = (x+1<WIDTH && y+1<HEIGHT)? img_in[(x+1)+(y+1)*WIDTH]:0;
        pixel = -1*LUp  + 1*RUp +
                -2*LCnt + 2*RCnt +
                -1*LDw  + 1*RDw;
        pixel=(pixel<0)?0:pixel;
        pixel=(pixel>MAXRGB)?MAXRGB:pixel;
        img_out[x+y*WIDTH]=pixel;
    }
}
```

The code is working for global memory and handles the boundary safely. My full code reads a BMP image and applies the filter on it and store the resulting BMP back to disk. It is available at [here](http://lashgar.hourb.com/files/edge_detection.tar.gz) (CPU and GPU implementations are integrated, both for Linux and Windows).

You can turn it to shared memory style with a bit of work. First, you should decide about how much task you give to each block. Then break the task into multiple shared memory sink/drains. Matrix Multiply example in CUDA SDK gives you a perfect idea.